# awk: split datetime column into three separate columns in a csv

Tags: linux, awk, csv

I am trying to use substr to split a datetime column, the fifth one (previous_test) into three different ones at the end.

Input:

```
id,tester,company,chief,previous_test,test,date,result,cost
6582983b-61d4-4371-912d-bbc76bb8208b,Audrey Feest,Pagac-Gorczany,Claudine Moakson,18/02/2019,Passwords,20/05/2020,none,¬£11897.96
```

Expected Output:

```
id,tester,company,chief,previous_test,test,date,result,cost,day,month,year
6582983b-61d4-4371-912d-bbc76bb8208b,Audrey Feest,Pagac-Gorczany,Claudine Moakson,18/02/2019,Passwords,20/05/2020,none,¬£11897.96,18,02,2019
```

I've tried using:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{s = substr($5, 1, 2)} {g = substr($5, 4, 2)} {l = substr($5, 7, 4)} {print s, g, l}' file.csv
```

And all I get is only the date separated by commas, but not as three additional columns appended to the existing columns.

I am missing how to append the output into three separate columns.

Comment: I fixed the formatting and tried to clarify your question as I understand it. Please check if this matches your intention. You print only the 3 substrings, not the existing columns. You need a special handling for the heading line. Please [edit] your question and specify if the input can contain more than one record of data (plus heading). If yes, show an example with at least two lines, the corresponding expected output and the actual output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code prints only the substring values that are intended for the new columns, not the existing columns.

You need a special handling for the first line.

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==1 { print $0,"day,month,year"; next }
{ s = substr($5, 1, 2);
  g = substr($5, 4, 2);
  l = substr($5, 7, 4);
  print $0, s, g, l}' file.csv
```

prints

```
id,tester,company,chief,previous_test,test,date,result,cost,day,month,year
6582983b-61d4-4371-912d-bbc76bb8208b,Audrey Feest,Pagac-Gorczany,Claudine Moakson,18/02/2019,Passwords,20/05/2020,none,¬£11897.96,18,02,2019
```

Explanation:

- The condition `NR==1` is valid for the first record/line.
- `$0` is the whole input record/line
- The `next` command jumps to the next record/line and skips all remaining commands for the current record/line. This means the other commands will be executed for all records/lines except the first one.

**Edit:** As suggested in a comment by [Olivier Dulac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/27616/olivier-dulac), the splitting of the date string can be simplified with the `split` function.

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==1 { print $0,"day,month,year"; next }
{ split($5,a,"/"); print $0, a[1], a[2], a[3] }' file.csv
```

Comment: quite good. another (maybe easier to process) way to retrieve each element of $5 : using `split(something,newarray,"regexp")` : for exemple here, the splitting regex can be simply "/" :   `split($5,a,"/"); s=a[1]; g=a[2]; l=a[3]`

Comment: This solved the problem perfectly! I understand that `print $0` prints the whole document but I don't get `next` command.

Comment: @LlemColop I added an explanation

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to split `$5`, just change the `/`s to `,`s then print it. With GNU awk for `gensub()`:

```
$ awk -F, '{print $0 FS (NR>1 ? gensub("/",FS,"g",$5) : "day,month,year") }' file
id,tester,company,chief,previous_test,test,date,result,cost,day,month,year
6582983b-61d4-4371-912d-bbc76bb8208b,Audrey Feest,Pagac-Gorczany,Claudine Moakson,18/02/2019,Passwords,20/05/2020,none,¬£11897.96,18,02,2019
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{d=$5; gsub("/",FS,d); print $0 FS (NR>1 ? d : "day,month,year") }' file
id,tester,company,chief,previous_test,test,date,result,cost,day,month,year
6582983b-61d4-4371-912d-bbc76bb8208b,Audrey Feest,Pagac-Gorczany,Claudine Moakson,18/02/2019,Passwords,20/05/2020,none,¬£11897.96,18,02,2019
```

Answer (score 1):

Done by below command

```
 awk -F "," 'NR==1{print $0",day,month,year"}NR == 2{print $0","substr($5,1,2)","substr($5,4,2)","substr($5,7,4)}' file
```

output

```
id,tester,company,chief,previous_test,test,date,result,cost,day,month,year
6582983b-61d4-4371-912d-bbc76bb8208b,Audrey Feest,Pagac-Gorczany,Claudine Moakson,18/02/2019,Passwords,20/05/2020,none,¬£11897.96,18,02,2019
```